# How to set the maximum width of an input node in an algorithm flowchart with LateX and tikz

Tags: latex, flowchart, fixed-width, tikz

I would like to set the width for a node, in particular, an Input/Output node in Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right
angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered,
draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (in1) [io] {Input};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code above generates the following node:
[image]

As the text inside grows so does the width of the Input node. But my question is if there is a way to set the width of the Input node beforehand or to give the Input node a maximum width.

Comment: Please  add a compilable [mre]. Please also note that `\tikzstyle` is obsolete. Have a look at `\tikzset` instead.

Comment: yes, it is not reproducible, but I am looking for a parameter, be it \tikstyle or \tikset to set a maximum width for such an algorithm flowchart node, if there is such a parameter. The length of that node adapts to the text inside. However, I want to limit it.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you should make it as easy as possible for them. Writing things like `\begin{document}` is just boring - you could do that for the users who are willing to invest their free time in searching a solution for you. Please add a compilable [mre].

Comment: I added the compilable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `trapezium stretches=true` option together with a fixed text width to make sure all your nodes have the same width.

If you have really long text, you could use the `adjustbox` option to automatically scale the text down to fit into your node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\tikzset{io/.style={
  trapezium, 
  trapezium left angle=70, 
  trapezium right angle=110, 
  text width=3cm, 
  minimum height=1cm, 
  text centered,
  draw=black, 
  fill=blue!30,
  trapezium stretches=true
  }}
  
\usepackage{adjustbox}  
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (in1) [io] {Input};
\node at (0,-2) [io] {\adjustbox{max width=3cm}{long text overflowing the shape}};
\node at (0,-4) [io] {Input Input};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]